# Connect from Windows host to QEMU inside Docker

Tags: windows, virtualization, docker, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to establish a connection between Windows 10 running Docker container (Linux), which runs QEMU to host a QNX OS. This picture should make it more clear:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuXtw.png)

I would like to highlight what I was able to reach so far:

1. From the host, I can ping the the IP inside the docker container: 10.0.75.2
2. From the docker container, I have established a tap interface and a VDE switch, and I can ping the QNX: 192.168.56.51

Commands used for initiating the environment:

```
#add new network interface
ip tuntap add mode tap dev tap0
ip addr add 192.168.56.1/24 dev tap0
ip link set dev tap0 up

#start vde switch connected to tap0
vde_switch -F -d -sock /tmp/myswitch -tap tap0

#start QEMU
qemu-system-x86_64  \
-m 1024  \
-cpu qemu64  \
-smp 2  \
-netdev vde,id=t0,sock=/tmp/myswitch  \
-device e1000,netdev=t0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:50  \
-drive file=/qnx/qnx_vm_x86_64-qemu.img  \
-D /var/log/qemu_err.log \
-serial file:/var/log/qemu_out.log  \
-display none -daemonize
```

Command to run the docker container:

```
docker run -it --rm --network=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --privileged qemu_qnx
```

What is missing is to be able to connect between the host and the QNX. Is it possible for example to forward the connection from Hvint0 to Tap0?

> Aside note: On Linux host, I can run the Docker container with
>   network=host, and I can access it from the host easily, but
>   unfortunately that wouldn't work on Windows host.

What I have tried so far unfortunately with no luck:

1. Do port forwarding for the QNX guest:

```
#flush iptables rules
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

#Add rule
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.51:22

#Save the iptables rule :
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

2. Start QEMU with hostfwd option, I can see the port is opened but I cannot ssh into it (doubting it can also be related to QNX network settings)

```
-device e1000,netdev=net0
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

Please let me know if there might be any more information I can provide.

Comment: I'm very confused, why are you attempting to run a virtual machine inside of a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows (and Mac) do not support the `--network=host` mode, as can be [read in the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.